# mpdf using while to print a table with data inside it and outside it

Tags: php, mpdf

I have a pdf document to print and everything is working fine until I need some data from the database to appear outside of the while loop.

Here is the code that I've used:

```
    <?php

session_start();
$role = $_SESSION['userrole'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['useruid']) || $role!="administrator"){
  header('Location: login.php?error=wrongrole');
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['useruid']) && $role!="tutor") {
  header('location: login.php?error=wrongrole');
}

require_once ('../vendor/autoload.php');
require_once ('dbh.inc.php');

$ids =  explode(',', $_GET['report-id']);

$query_params = [];
$bind_params = '';

foreach($ids as $id){
    $query_params[] = '?';
    $bind_params .= 'i';
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from planning 
                        INNER JOIN classes on classes.classesClass = planning.planningClass
                        WHERE planningId IN(" . implode(',', $query_params) . ")");
$stmt->bind_param($bind_params, ...$ids);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => '/tmp']);

$html = '
<img src="../img/ue-logo.jpg" height="60" width="auto" />
<img style="padding-left: 32%;" src="../img/gr-logo.jpg" height="60" width="auto" />
<img style="padding-left: 32%;" src="../img/is-logo.jpg" height="60" width="auto" />

<br /><br />

<p style="text-align: right; padding-right: 5%;"><strong>ANEXA 4</strong></p>

<br />

<p style="text-align: left;"><strong>
  id 130788<br />
  "Proiect “Stagii de practică pentru elevii din învățământul tehnic – calificări în servicii”, cod SMIS 130788"<br />
  Centralizator activitati stagii de practica luna $MONTH
</strong></p>

<h3 style="text-align: center;">PLANIFICAREA TEMATICA LUNA $MONTH </h3>

<br/>

<table style="border:1px solid black; width:100%; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;">
  <tr style="border:1px solid black;">
    <th style="border:1px solid black;">Clasa</th>
    <th style="border:1px solid black;">Domeniu/Sc Profesioanala/Liceu</th>
    <th style="border:1px solid black;">Saptamana</th>
    <th style="border:1px solid black;">Ora start - Ora terminare</th>
    <th style="border:1px solid black;">Angajator</th>
  </tr>
';

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $html .= '
    <tr>
      <td style="border:1px solid black;">' . $row['planningClass'] . '</td>
      <td style="border:1px solid black;">' . $row['classesQualification'] . '</td>
      <td style="border:1px solid black;">' . $row['planningWeek'] .'</td>
      <td style="border:1px solid black;">' . $row['planningHourStart'] . ' - ' . $row['planningHourEnd'] . '</td>
      <td style="border:1px solid black;">' . $row['planningCompany'] .'</td>
    </tr>';
}

$html .= '</table>';

$mpdf->AddPage('L');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);


$mpdf->Output();
```

The thing is I need the month from the database to appear before I initialize the while loop. How can I do this? Is there a simple way? I've put $MONTH where I want the data from the loop to be.

Comment: You will need to fetch the first row out of your result set before the loop then. (I assume you have made sure that your query can return results for one single month only already? Because otherwise, this wouldn't make much sense to begin with.) And then reset the record pointer to the start, so that your loop does not skip the first record.

Comment: The query doesn't block the month, I will format the variable to be the smallest month selected.

Comment: Your query does not even apply any ORDERing, so you won't be able to tell which is the lowest months to begin with, unless you go over _all_ records first.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. To do this I needed to first fetch all the data from the result set. Can use fetch_all() for multiple rows, else can be optimized with fetch_array().

Then needed to access the row at index 0 and its key to get the value from the needed column. If there are no rows or the column is not part of the SQL then the default can be an empty string.